# Favicon not found in Django in production

Tags: django, favicon

The favicon.ico is not found, 404 error, when a Django app is running in production.

I set the icon in app/favicon.ico, so I put the icon in mysite/static/app/favicon.ico.

In html,

The icon is in myproject/static/app/favicon.ico as in the static folder in production.

[image]

Comment: What does the 404 message say in the server logs? Browsers usually request www.example.com/favicon.ico too even though you specify a different location.

Comment: Did you set `STATIC_ROOT` in your `settings.py`? and did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: The error message says.. the icon is not found because it looks for the icon in the full url/app/favicon.ico.. so for http://example.com/user/ url, the browser looks for http://example.com/user/app/favicon.ico.

Comment: Simple mistake. forgo to put {% static 'app/favicon.ico' %} in coding.. Thanks all.